# Создать объект рандомного класса-наследника

Tags: php, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Допустим, есть родительский класс `PhpFunction`, а также несколько его наследников: `StringFunction`, `CharFunction`, `ArrayFunction`, `MathFunciton`.

Как можно через интерфейс родительского класса создать объект случайного класса-наследника?

```
$a = PhpFunction::createRandFunc(); // объект класса CharFunction
$b = PhpFunction::createRandFunc(); // объект класса MathFunction
$a = PhpFunction::createRandFunc(); // объект класса CharFunction
```

Интересует, как можно реализовать такое с помощью встроенных средств работы с классами языка PHP, а также всевозможные шаблоны, способные решить данную задачу, если таковые имеются.

Comment: С помощью `switch`/`if-else`.

Comment: Также советую вынести данный функционал в другой класс, например, `PhpFuncionFactory`

Comment: Создаёте фабрику с массивом классов, затем внутри этой функции выбираете случайное число от/до размера массива, и возвращаете новый объект по классу из массива. Пример (итоговый) для функции : return new $Classes[$RandomIndex]();